# Thoth.Json.Net – Decoder as a Functor, is it possible?

Tags: f#, f#+

I have found [this](https://thoth-org.github.io/Thoth.Json/) superb JSON library for F#, it's inspired by Elm's Json.Decode and it defines a basic `Decoder` type like this:

`type Decoder<'T> = string -> obj -> Result<'T, DecoderError>` [(here)](https://github.com/thoth-org/Thoth.Json.Net/blob/35402a9d8b8b5efd7c61cb1959907a6606fd83f6/src/Types.fs#L24)

There are functions like [Decode.map](https://github.com/thoth-org/Thoth.Json.Net/blob/35402a9d8b8b5efd7c61cb1959907a6606fd83f6/src/Decode.fs#L548) and I wish I could make it F#+ compatible, so I could use it like:

`let customerId = Decode.string |>> CustomerId`
(see [|>>](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus//reference/fsharpplus-operators.html#(%20%7C%3E%3E%20)) infix version of generic map)

As far as I can see, to make a 3rd party library use F#+ concepts like Functors, one needs to extend the 3rd party type with `static member Map`, but the `Decoder<'T>` is just an abbreviation.

Is there any solution? Did anyone try?

P.S.
My solution so far is a custom binding:

```
let (<!>) = Decode.map
let customerId: Decoder<CustomerId> = CustomerId <!> Decode.string
let submitId: Decoder<SubmitId> = SubmitId <!> Decode.string
let currency: Decoder<Currency> = Currency <!> Decode.string
// etc…
```

Comment: Could you not make `Decoder` a single-case DU? Or do you not control it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't control the code. If you had control over it, a solution would be:

- Implement `Decoder` as a concrete type as opposed to a type alias. A type alias can't have additional members, because it's not really another type. Library authors should use single case discriminated unions, now that you can make them structs with nearly zero overhead.
- Add the member `Map` with the required signature.

Alternatively, if extensions members becomes visible for trait constraints in a future F# version, you would be able just extend the type with the Map function, maybe with some undesired effects as it's a type alias for a function with 2 arguments.

So, I think the best you can do is what you already showed.

As a side note, you might be interested in having a look at [Fleece](https://github.com/fsprojects/Fleece) which also provides decoders, but it also goes one step further and provides you codecs which goes in both directions (and you can `map` and `<*>` over it).